# Init with code only in specific class

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, ntp

```
-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        if ([[self class]isKindOfClass:[SplashScreenViewController class]])
        {

        NetworkClock * nc = [NetworkClock sharedNetworkClock];
         self.networkTime = nc.networkTime;


            [self shortTest];
        }else
        {


        }

    }
    return self;
}
```

It doesnt work for me. I want to execute NetworkClock code only in specific class in other classes should perform normal "clear" init. Do you know smart way

Comment: What class are you in? I think what you're searching for is the *viewDidLoad*-method not *init*

Comment: In SplashScreenViewController viewDidLoad i Did [Myclass alloc]init]
and I want to execute this code :  NetworkClock * nc = [NetworkClock sharedNetworkClock];
         self.networkTime = nc.networkTime; only if init is in SSVC in other classes clear init

Comment: That doesn't look correct at all. Please add the code to your question. The *init* method is specific to your ViewController. It's not being called from any other class than SplashScreenViewController (except you had a subclass which you usually shouldn't from a VC)

Comment: What code ? I need in init check what class is initing just all but kindofclass dosent work.

Comment: The code from your SplashCreenViewController. I'm not sure if you understood what the init method does. It is being called then 'somebody' initializes your SplashScreenViewController. self.class is always going to return SplashCreenViewController